# How to prevent a JsConfig scope from affecting global settings

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

In `AppHost.Configure` I set a global JSON config `JsConfig.TreatEnumAsInteger = false;` and have a simple handler with two GET endpoints

```
public object Get(GetDayOfWeekAsText request)
{
    return new GetDayOfWeekResponse();
}

public object Get(GetDayOfWeekAsInt request)
{
    return new HttpResult(new GetDayOfWeekResponse())
    {
        ResultScope = () => JsConfig.With(new Config
        {
            TreatEnumAsInteger = true
        })
    };
}
```

Depending on the request I call first all subsequent requests will serialize enums as text or integer until the application is recycled. Explicitly setting `TreatEnumAsInteger` in `GetDayOfWeekAsText` has no effect.

Thanks!

Comment: The config impl has changed recently, can you confirm if this is still an issue with the latest v5.4.0 on NuGet?

Comment: Yes. Looked into it a bit further. `TreatEnumAsInteger` is used globally depending on the first endpoint hit. The `Emit___Names` values affect other requests sporadically. Seems like it might be caused by IIS thread re-use.

Answer (score 0):

This should now be resolved with [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/ee8c70d871f5d613e8ffb5316d4c3e7f8401ecf0).

This change is available from v5.4.1 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).